# Persistence.xml issue while upgrading application from eap5 to eap7

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I am upgrading my application from eap5 to eap7.

Issue while deploying the .ear file - the persistence.xml file is not able to read the entity classes.

The persistence.xml file is located like this in the .ear file 
.ear->lib -> xxx.jar -> META-INF->persistence.xml.

All the entity classes are located like 
.ear->lib->xxx.jar->xdirectory->xsubdirectory->*.class

WARN: [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 176) HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class:

I see these WARN and then followed by ERROR 
ERROR: ERROR [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 176) HHH000177: Error in named query:

I tried explicitly putting the entity.class file in the persistence.xml using  (will have to put all the classes that I did not like)
all the warning and errors went away.

Is there any other approach to resolve this error.

I am trying using  but did not have any luck yet.

Comment: There are a lot of Hibernate and JPA Migration Changes from EAP 5 to EAP 7. Verify the Migration change guide and follow the steps: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/migration_guide/#hibernate_and_jpa_migration_changes

double check in persistence.xml if any Entity classes are missing.

Comment: - Make sure that you have the right mapping entry in the persistence.xml file.
-  double check if persistence.xml lack of any class

Answer (score 0):

This issue is got resolved. In TMS application Entity manager is getting created in 2 ways 1. Managed 2.Unmanaged

Managed - In all EJBs with @PersistenceContext
Unmanged - To get DB connection in test cases. To load static tables as Constants in server start up.

While creating entity manger in a unmanged way entity manager is is not loading entities unless specified specifically in persistence xml. (On this our team was constantly touch based with red hat team. They mentioned that this feature will be added in next releases).

We solved this problem by getting static table values through managed entity manager same as ModelConstants.